# DirectX - Drawing with GDI on a IDirect3DTexture9

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I am trying to draw text using GDI `TextOutA` on a IDirect3DTexture9 however i dont see anything on screen.

Here is my code:

```
HFONT pFont = CreateFontA(-10 * nLogPixelsY / 72, 0, 0, 0, 700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Arial");

IDirect3DTexture9* pFontTex = NULL;
pDXDevice->CreateTexture(100, 100, 1, 0, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &pFontTex, NULL);

////////////////////////////

IDirect3DSurface9* ppSurface = NULL;
HDC mDC = NULL;
if (pFontTex->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &ppSurface) == D3D_OK)
{
    if (ppSurface->GetDC(&mDC) == D3D_OK)
    {
        SelectObject(mDC, pFont);
        SetTextColor(mDC, 0x00FF00FF);
        SetBkMode(mDC, TRANSPARENT);
        TextOutA(mDC, 0, 0, "Test", 4);

        //MessageBoxA(0, "work", 0, 0);

        ppSurface->ReleaseDC(mDC);
    }

    ppSurface->Release();
}

pDXDevice->SetTexture(0, pFontTex);
pDXDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHATESTENABLE, TRUE);
pDXDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAFUNC, D3DCMP_GREATEREQUAL);
pDXDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAREF, 0x01);
pDXDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN, 0, 2);
```

Comment: You haven't said if any of your DX calls fail. Do `GetSurfaceLevel` and `GetDC` actually succeed? If not, what error code do you get?

Comment: All of them succeeded, i traced them using a debugger.